# cannot read data from Json hosted on GitHub

Tags: swift, github, codable

when try to read data from a json on my GitHub space, I get an error

nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed
Invalid response from the server. Please try again.

am I using wrong url or there is an issue in the way I'm parsing data?

my repo url

```
https://github.com/stark226/stark226.github.io.git
```

where there is a simple json file at this url

```
https://github.com/stark226/stark226.github.io/blob/3b2bebb4a3d85524732c7e7ec302b24f8d3e66ae/testjson.json
```

in my viewDidload

```
getDataFromJsonOnGithub(completed: { [weak self] result in
            guard let self = self else {return}
            
            switch result {
            case .success(let expected):
                print(expected)
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error.rawValue)
            }
            
        })
```

my struct

```
struct RemoteData: Codable, Hashable {
    var tokenDuration: Int
}
```

my func

```
func getDataFromJsonOnGithub(completed: @escaping (Result<RemoteData, ListOfErrors>) -> Void) {

    let endpoint = "https://github.com/stark226/stark226.github.io/stark226/testjson.json"
    
    guard let url = URL(string: endpoint) else {
        completed(.failure(.invalidUsername))
        return
    }
    
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        
        if let _ = error {
            completed(.failure(.unableToComplete))
            return
        }
        
        guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 200 else {
            completed(.failure(.invalidResponse))
            return
        }
        
        guard let data = data else {
            completed(.failure(.invalidData))
            return
        }
        
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
            let expectedRrsult = try decoder.decode(RemoteData.self, from: data)
            completed(.success(expectedRrsult))
        } catch {
            completed(.failure(.invalidData))
        }
    }
    
    task.resume()
}



enum ListOfErrors: String, Error {
    
    case invalidUsername    = "This username created an invalid request. Please try again."
    case unableToComplete   = "Unable to complete your request. Please check your internet connection"
    case invalidResponse    = "Invalid response from the server. Please try again."
    case invalidData        = "The data received from the server was invalid. Please try again."
    case unableToFavorite   = "There was an error favoriting this user. Please try again."
    case alreadyInFavorites = "You've already favorited this user. You must REALLY like them!"
}
```

Comment: You have to access the raw file. The page you are accessing is an HTML page.
Try the following url (click on Raw button in GitHub):
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stark226/stark226.github.io/3b2bebb4a3d85524732c7e7ec302b24f8d3e66ae/testjson.json

Comment: how can I achieve that?

Comment: by using the correct url or any url which returns JSON. I have already posted it.

Comment: thanks! did not see the update, it is working! if you want to give this as answer I can check it as solved

Comment: Why the `weak self - guard` dance? `self` is not being used in the closure. And even if `self` was used there is optional chaining in Swift (`self?.doSomething()`). And you are strongly discouraged from ignoring the **real** DecodingErrror. `.invalidData ` is meaningless

Comment: again a precious help, Vadian! here self is not useful, but in other calls my TM prefers this check, he says there are less chances of retain circles, or something like that.

Comment: updated with my list of errors

Comment: The `weak self` statement is not bad per se. No offense but your TM seems to be an old-fashioned Objective-C guy. Many things in Swift work differently.

Comment: no offense at all, learning by myself is like hell, online courses do not teach real life, stack end people like you are priceless

Comment: Catch the error, at minima, print it. To help you, you can also print the data (and you would have seen your issue): `} catch { print("Error while decoding: \(error) with \(String(data:data, encoding: .utf8)"; completion(.failure(.invalidata))  }`

Comment: testing your catch in place of my             completed(.failure(.invalidData))
 but not working, cannot correct it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to access the raw file.
 The URL you are accessing renders an HTML page. Try the following url (click on "Raw" button in GitHub):
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stark226/stark226.github.io/3b2bebb4a3d85524732c7e7ec302b24f8d3e66ae/testjson.json